# CCFiniteTimeAction::getDuration() EXC_BAD_ACCESS when creating a CCSequence

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, ios-simulator, cocos2d-x

I was able to run this code without getting an error on the iPhone simulator.  However, when I run it on my iPhone,  I am getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.  Here is the code:

```
        CCAnimate * explosionAnimate = CCAnimate::create(explosionAnimation);
        CCCallFuncN * callFuncN = CCCallFuncN::create(this,callfuncN_selector(GameLayer::removeChildFromParent));
        CCFiniteTimeAction * explosionSequence = CCSequence::create(explosionAnimate, callFuncN);

        CCSprite * explosionSprite = CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("explosion_frame_1");
        addChild(explosionSprite);

        explosionSprite->setPosition(point);
        explosionSprite->runAction(explosionSequence);
    }

    void GameLayer::removeChildFromParent(CCNode * child)
    {
        child->removeFromParent();
    }
```

The error occurs when CCSequence::create(...) is called.  Debugging through CCSequence::create(...)

```
CCFiniteTimeAction* CCSequence::create(CCFiniteTimeAction *pAction1, va_list args)
{
    CCFiniteTimeAction *pNow;
    CCFiniteTimeAction *pPrev = pAction1;

    while (pAction1)
    {
        pNow = va_arg(args, CCFiniteTimeAction*);
        if (pNow)
        {
            pPrev = createWithTwoActions(pPrev, pNow);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return pPrev;
}
```

I am seeing that "createWithTwoActions" get's called twice.  That doesn't seem right.  On the 2nd call to "createWithTwoActions".  The error occurs within CCFiniteTimeAction, specifically at the getDuration() inline function:

```
inline float getDuration(void) { return m_fDuration; }
```

Any ideas why this would be occurring?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to resolve the issue by calling CCSequence::create() like:

```
CCSequence::create(explosionAnimate, callFuncN, NULL);
```

instead of:

```
CCSequence::create(explosionAnimate, callFuncN);
```

I'm guessing this has to do with the nature of CCFiniteAction pointers and C++ variable length arguments.

Comment: correct, you must signal the end of the argument list with a NULL pointer. Alternatively in your case, you can use CCSequence::createWithTwoActions() which does not require NULL (for instance, it is sometimes useful when you want to pass a sequence to an action like CCRepeatForever).