# My iPhone app with cocos2d-x crashes only in Ad-hoc build

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, adhoc

My cocos2d-x app crashes in Ad-hoc build, even though it works fine in debug-mode.

Just after the app launches, it crashes.

The situation may be similar to the issue here.
[Cocos2d-x app only crashes in Ad-hoc build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084299/cocos2d-x-app-only-crashes-in-ad-hoc-build)

But as I don't use CocosBuilder, it must have happened with different reason.
(I tried to fix following the advice but my app didn't work.)

Crash report is:

```
Incident Identifier: CEE9C97F-CCA7-4769-B17B-AD39AF709B28
CrashReporter Key:   7bad3b03fac96eca686dbc9f7de90780e15c35d3
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:         myapp [2855]
Path:
/var/mobile/Applications/7A2BA957-8ACE-46BD-9FBB-79FAF1BD4DCB/myapp.app/myapp
Identifier:      myapp
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-04-15 17:37:06.354 +0900
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.3 (10B329)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN at 0x331cb869
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   myapp                              0x000161e2 0x1000 + 86498
1   myapp                              0x000162aa 0x1000 + 86698
2   myapp                              0x00016286 0x1000 + 86662
3   myapp                              0x00013ae0 0x1000 + 76512
4   myapp                              0x0001c328 0x1000 + 111400
5   myapp                              0x0001de1a 0x1000 + 118298
6   myapp                              0x0001b636 0x1000 + 108086
7   myapp                              0x0001c04c 0x1000 + 110668
8   QuartzCore                          0x331ca094
CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch(unsigned long long, unsigned long
long) + 156
9   QuartzCore                          0x331c9fec
CA::Display::IOMFBDisplayLink::callback(__IOMobileFramebuffer*,
unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, void*) +
60
10  IOMobileFramebuffer                 0x35447fd4
IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 152
11  IOKit                               0x321c4446
IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 190
12  CoreFoundation                      0x315a75d8 __CFMachPortPerform + 116
13  CoreFoundation                      0x315b2170
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
14  CoreFoundation                      0x315b2112 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
15  CoreFoundation                      0x315b0f94 __CFRunLoopRun + 1380
16  CoreFoundation                      0x31523eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
17  CoreFoundation                      0x31523d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
18  GraphicsServices                    0x350fc2e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
19  UIKit                               0x334392fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
20  myapp                              0x00012db6 0x1000 + 73142
21  myapp                              0x0000229c 0x1000 + 4764
```

Can anyone tell me how to deal with?

Thanks

Comment: check your build configuration mode may be are running the app  in distribution mode.

Comment: Does the app also crash if you build release configuration, or only if you build an adhoc (which builds release, too)? You may have an issue that always occurs in release builds, if so that would actually make it easier to track down.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by myself referring

[CCFiniteTimeAction::getDuration() EXC_BAD_ACCESS when creating a CCSequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923788/ccfinitetimeactiongetduration-exc-bad-access-when-creating-a-ccsequence)

An array was not ended with NULL, so it didn't work. As I was too much focusing on running the app, I missed the important and basic thing.

Thanks for your comment, Madhusudhan and LearnCocos2D.